# What is the "scale" parameter in "continuous autoregressive model" in cts package?

Tags: r, time-series, scales, continuous-data, autoregressive

I am trying to use the "car" command in "cts package" in R program and I see the "scale" parameter there. I wonder whether this can be assumed to be equivalent to time intervals for time series forecasting. 
For example, the code is like this:

```
car(x, y=NULL, scale = 1.5, order = 3, ctrl=car_control())
```

and the official cts package explanation is the following:

> scale: The kappa value referred to in the paper by Belcher et a.
>   (1994).We now recommend selection of kappa along with the model order
>   by using AIC. Also, it is suggested to choose kappa close to 2pi times
>   1/mean.delta (reciprocal of the mean time between observations),
>   though it is a good idea to explore somewhat lower and higher values
>   to see whether the spectrum estimates were sensitive to this choice.
>   Choosing kappa lower increases the risk of trying to estimate the
>   spectrum beyond the effective Nyquist frequency of the data - though
>   this does depend on the distribution of intersample times.

Can anyone have some ideas, please..?

Answer (score 1):

It says explicitly in the section you quote:

"*it is suggested to choose $κ$ close to $2π$ times [... the] reciprocal of the mean time between observations*".

So it's proportional to frequency of observations (1/*average time interval*) not the time interval. [They also give a reference which no doubt has an explicit definition as well.]